# How to create a Servlet that generates PDF (Servlet code and web.xml needed)

Tags: itext

I created a servlet class that produces a PDF document using iText. Then I mapped that servlet correctly in the `web.xml` of my application server, so that I can view the PDF in a Web browser through the URL I defined. Unfortunately, it's not working. The servlet class I used was the one explained in the book "iText in Action - second edition". I don't know if I implemented it wrongly or if I need an extra library that takes care of the contents added to the Servlet.

I need some help on how to use the hello world example Servlet class in "iText in Action - second edition" and view it on Web browser. If anyone has complete source code or a video tutorial on how that can be implemented could you please share it?

Comment: Hi Joseph. I updated your question because it's not done on StackOverflow to share you mail address. Answers to questions should be posted on StackOverflow, not sent to people off-site.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the full code of the book "iText in Action - Second Edition", please go to the [official web site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/), select the [examples section](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples) and pick the category [iText in Action](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition). Now go to [Chapter 9](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-9). This page has the full sample code of chapter 9 in the book. If you scroll down, you can even download the original raw code (no need to copy/paste).

If you go to the page with the [iText demos](http://itextpdf.com/itext-demos) and you scroll down, you can find links to the Servlets in action:

- [Creating a PDF on the fly](http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/hello.pdf)
- [Creating a PDF on the fly showing text passed as a parameter](http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/)
- [Creating PDF from JSP](http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/helloworld.jsp) (don't do this, use a servlet instead)
- [XML](http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/movies.xml) to [PDF](http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/movies) (*)
- [Posting form data in different ways](http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/submit_me.pdf) (*)
- [Posting a simple form](http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/form) (*)
- [XFDF example](http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/xfdf) (*)
- [FDF example](http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/fdf) (*)
- [Create FDF](http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/fdf_form.html)
- [JavaScript connection between HTML and PDF](http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/javascript.html) (*)

The examples marked with (*) require a full-blown PDF viewer as browser plug-in. They will work when using Adobe Reader, but not necessarily with other applications such as PDF.js or Chrome PDF viewer.

The hello world servlet ([Hello.java](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-9#372-hello.java)) should work with any PDF viewer: http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/hello.pdf

The `WebContent` needed to run some examples can be found in GitLab. The same goes for the `web.xml`:

- http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/book/tree/master/WebContent
- http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/book/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

If you are only interested in the `Hello.java` servlet, this is what your `web.xml` would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>book</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>Hello</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
        part3.chapter09.Hello</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello.pdf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now you have all the examples you need. The only thing that might be missing is knowing how to deploy a Servlet on an Application server such as Tomcat. But I'm pretty sure you know how to do that. If not, please don't post such a question on StackOverflow, as that would be off-topic.

Comment: If you down-vote an answer, at least have the decency to explain why you're down-voting that answer. Granted, the question is bad, but does that also mean you have to down-vote good answers to bad questions???